# AppInsights see response to requests

Tags: azure-application-insights, appinsights

Is there a way to see the response to a request in the logs generated through appinsights?

I’ve got several apis, and I can see the client making the calls when querying the requests table, I can see the status of the request but I can’t see what was sent back to the client.

Also when I click appinsights in my APIs it says

‘Set up app insights without changing code’

But above it, there’s a green tick saying ‘connected by Instrumentation code’

Does this mean it’s connected and working?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean it’s connected and working?

Yes, Application Insight connected to API.

> Is there a way to see the response to a request in the logs generated through App insights?

If you want to see the **response of your request/Custom Events or Custom Metrics**, you need to use the **Custom Telemetry** in your API to get the response in Application insights.

**Note:** Make sure you can use it for testing purpose. In an application insight who ever have the access of your subscription of the specific resource they can view the telemetry data.

#### Reference

- [Custom Metrics in API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics)